# Jquery trying to get value from inner table inside tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html-table

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td style="background-color:white">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-row-id="22">
          <td id="pid"><input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" value="8843" data-id="22"><label class="pid 8843">8843</label></td>
          <td style="width: 120px">QCH/H3E/TCZN0D </td>
          <td style="width: 270px">Territory Health Intermediate Hospital 500 With Essential Extras </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <button class="btn btn-success 8843 pull-right" id="approve-row" data-id="22" href="javascript: void(0)" style="display:none">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Approve</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td style="padding:0">
    <table>
      ----
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am using jQuery datatable and in each row I have tables with inner tables.
I am able to get the required table from the datatable list using:

`$(this).closest('table').closest('table tr')[0]`

But I am not able to get the pid value which is inside

```
<label class="pid 8843">
```

I want to find the pid value. Each row has different pid values. For example:

```
  <label class="pid 2">
  <label class="pid 3">
  <label class="pid 4">
  ...
```

I have found the correct tr in which my pid value resides but how to get the pid value is a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not use the class of label instead? `$('.pid.8843')`?

Comment: reach $('.pid.8843') is a problem. How can i find pid.8843 from there. Each row has different pid values like pid 12, pid 13 etc. I am able to find the correct row where my pid value is but how to get there is a problem

Comment: are the class dynamically added that you can use it in selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the structure is same in you table, just target label and class to get that attr,, like this:

:EDIT (target input, even better)

```
$( $(this).closest('table').closest('table tr')[0] ).find('input').val()
```

try again please

Comment: I dont see that the label has any attribute called `pid`

Comment: He need to get the "value" aka the number from the class from a label. `.val()`does not work

Comment: yea, but the nuber is the same as value of the input box

Comment: i am getting this error "AuditLogResults:40892 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).closest(...)[0].find is not a function"

Comment: test it again @OwaisAhmed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('button').closest('table').find('tr:first td:first').find('label').attr('class')
```

```js
console.log($('button').closest('table').find('tr:first td:first').find('label').attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="pid"><input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" value="8843" data-id="22"><label class="pid 8843">8843</label></td>
          <td style="width: 120px">QCH/H3E/TCZN0D </td>
          <td style="width: 270px">Territory Health Intermediate Hospital 500 With Essential Extras </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <button class="btn btn-success 8843 pull-right" id="approve-row" data-id="22" href="javascript: void(0)">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Approve</i>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: well this is only giving me the first pid in the datatable list

Comment: Do you want all the `pid` from table ?

Comment: no just the selected object pid which is inside $(this).closest('table').closest('table tr')